# Google analytics in Prestashop 1.7 admin

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, prestashop, admin, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to insert Google Analytics into our backoffice, does anyone have found the good file to edit or a module for this ?

So far I tried with /admin/themes/templates/header.tpl but it failed sadly.

Did anyone achieved to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit two files :

- For the login page :
  /admin/themes/default/template/controllers/login/header.tpl
- For all others : /admin/themes/new-theme/template/header.tpl

Then just add literal in smarty template to escape the JS from being executed :

```
{literal}
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXX-X'); // Replace your UA here
</script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: Why is there two different folder ? Thanks it's working :)

Comment: Dunno but seems to be for 1.6 migration support. Don't forget to flag as accepted :)